# How to convert a string to time in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a countdowntimer in Javascript. There are a lof of examples on the internet. I'm trying to adjust these to my own needs. I want a countdown timer that, when started, countsdown to the whole hour. For example, if I run the code at 13:15 it wil count down to 14:00.

The problem I have is getting the time to countdown to.

```
var cd = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();
```

In the above example you have a defined date. I'm trying to change this to a time to the first upcoming hour. Below is what I have:

```
var countdowndate = newDate("cd.getMonth, cd.getYear (cd.getHour + 1):00:00").getTime();
```

This isn't working. What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Anurag Srivastava. Yes your answer and fjc answer helped me. It helped me to adjust it to my specific needs. I really appreciate both your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very expressive way of solving this:

1. Get the current time stamp, floored to the last full minute.
2. Get how many full minutes remain until the next hour, transform to milliseconds.
3. Sum up the results of 1 and 2.

```js
function getBeginningOfNextHour() {
    const msPerMinute = 60 * 1000;
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const currentDateTimestampRoundedToMinute = Math.floor(+currentDate / msPerMinute) * msPerMinute;
    const msUntilNextHour = (60 - currentDate.getMinutes()) * msPerMinute;

    return new Date(currentDateTimestampRoundedToMinute + msUntilNextHour);
}

console.log(getBeginningOfNextHour());
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.Your post helped me to find a solution for my specific needs.